# CSS3 - transform:translate property when clicking on a link

Tags: css, scroll, navigation, css-animations, transform

I added a navigation bar to my website using this code on mobile (just edited a bit so it scrolls down from the top):

https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/qomrMw

Is there any way to make the menu to scroll back (close) when I click the links? 
I have a single page website with anchor links that scroll to each section, so if the menu doesn't close my content slides underneath..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. You can use this way. May this is not the best solution but its work.

Use **sidemenu** ID in **ul** tag and **list** class in every **li** tag. Then use the following JavaScript code inside the **script** tag.

```
const elements = document.getElementById('sidemenu');
elements.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('list')) {
    document.getElementById('sidebarMenu').style.transform =
      'translateX(-250px)';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be super clean but I sorted out the problem with this script which reload the Navigation Bar after clicking the links and works fine in my case

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $(".list").click(function(evt) {
     $("#mobile-nav").load("#mobile-nav")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})
</script>
```